# Как с помощью Ansible выполнить команду на удаленных хостах через telnet?

Tags: ansible, telnet, devops

Есть множество удаленных хостов, доступ к которым есть только по telnet.
Нужно изменить дефолтный пароль для этих хостов, для этого требуется:
1. Подключиться по телнет с пользователм admin и паролем admin
2. Ввести команду password 
3. Ввести новый пароль, подтвердить его
4. Завершить сессию командой logout

Вручную это выглядит так:

```
$telnet 10.46.18.1
Trying 10.46.18.1...
Connected to 10.46.18.1.
Login:admin
Password:admin
#
# password
Enter new password:
Confirm new password:
#
# logout
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

Написал плейбук следующего содержания, используя модуль expect:

```
---

- hosts: Test
  gather_facts: false
  connection: local
  tasks:
  - name: telnet,login and execute command
    ignore_errors: true
    expect:
      command: telnet "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
      responses:
        (?i)Login: "admin\n\r"
        (?i)Password: "admin\n\r"
        (?i)#: "config user\n\r"
        (?i)\(config-user\)#: "password\n\r"
        (?i)Enter new password: "admin123\n\r"
        (?i)Confirm new password: "admin123\n\r"
        (?i)#: "logout\r"
      echo: yes
    register: telnet_output
  - name: Debug output
    debug: var=telnet_output.stdout_lines
```

Но проблема возникает на последнем шаге, когда нужно сделать logout.
Проблема в том, что консоль удаленного устройства после смены пароля не выдает никакого сообщения об успехе, а отдает дефолтный символ терминала **#** и, по-видимому, ансибл входит в бесконечный цикл, начиная с (?i)**#**: "config user\n\r"

Вторым вариантом я попробовал модуль telnet:

```
---
- name: Test
  hosts: Test
  gather_facts: False
  tasks:
    - telnet:
        user: admin
        password: admin
        login_prompt: "Login:"
        prompts:
          - "[>|#]"
        command:
          - show basic
          - logout
```

Но при запуске алгоритма, ничего не происходит, процесс зависает:

```
ansible-playbook playbooks/telnet.yml

PLAY [Test] *****************************************************************************

TASK [telnet] *****************************************************************************************
```

Все-таки как мне обойти несколько десятков хостов по телнету?

Comment: Я так понимаю, что какой-нить htop на удалённом хосте - не вариант?

Comment: Не вариант. А при чем тут htop?

Comment: Ну в htop можно посмотреть в некоторых случаях на каком этапе выполнения находится тот или иной скрипт.

Comment: Поставте timeout 10 вы хотя бы увидете telnet_output.stdout_lines и в первом варианте перевод на новую строку "\n" вы случаем не забыли в последней команде?